# How to write natural deduction trees in LaTeX.

Tags: packages, logic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best package out there to typeset proof trees?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468/what-is-the-best-package-out-there-to-typeset-proof-trees)

Is there some package to use in order to write nice natural deductions (logical deduction trees)?

Examples are appreciated!

Here are some examples of [Natural deductions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction).

Comment: Examples of what you would like to do are also appreciated.  Can you provide a link or an image?  Is [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468/1402) relevant?

Comment: Please have a look at http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/

Comment: @Yiannis could you make your comment an answer?

Comment: @Yiannis: Lazarides: That is exactly what I look for, thanks!

Comment: @Matthew Leingang: Yes, that is the thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please have a look at  http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/