# semantic proof trees in ConTeXt

Tags: context, context-mkiv, logic

I want to draw logic proof trees in ConTeXt. Specifically, I want to be able to draw trees like this:
[image: proof tree]

I am aware that there are nice ways of doing this in LaTeX, and that the question [What is the best package out there to typeset proof trees?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468/what-is-the-best-package-out-there-to-typeset-proof-trees) already shows how. Are there clean ways to do it with ConTeXt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a quick workaround (in easy cases, *MKIV-only*), you could use [Aditya](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/323/aditya)'s wonderful [`filter` module](http://modules.contextgarden.net/filter) to make use of the LaTeX package (I picked `bussproofs`).  This is explained [in the documentation](http://dl.contextgarden.net/modules/t-filter/doc/context/third/filter/filter.txt), I just minimally altered it:

```
\usemodule[filter]
\defineexternalfilter
   [prooftree]
   [filter=pdflatex,
    output=\externalfilterbasefile.pdf,
    readcommand=\readPDFfile,
   ]

\def\readPDFfile#1{\externalfigure[#1]}
\startbuffer[prooftree::before]
  \documentclass{minimal}
  \usepackage{bussproofs}
  \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{preview}
  \begin{prooftree}
\stopbuffer

\startbuffer[prooftree::after]
  \end{prooftree}
  \end{preview}
  \end{document}
\stopbuffer

\setupexternalfilter
  [prooftree]
  [bufferbefore={prooftree::before},
   bufferafter={prooftree::after}]

\starttext

This is a {\em bussproofs} prooftree in \Context:

\startprooftree
\AxiomC{$\Gamma, A \vdash B$}
\LeftLabel{Conditional Proof:}
\UnaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash A \rightarrow B$}
\stopprooftree

\stoptext
```

This could be made more convenient (by writing better ConTeXt macros, I suppose) to include references to the trees-as-pictures.

Comment: FWIW, the `filter` module works with MkII as well.