# Drawing parse trees

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, packages, trees

I'm trying to draw parse trees for mathematical expressions such as `(x + (y - z))`.

When I google for parse trees in LaTeX, all I get are packages that produce an output similar to the style of [this package](http://www.essex.ac.uk/linguistics/external/clmt/latex4ling/trees/parsetree/):

[image: The wrong parse tree!]

However, the notation used at my university doesn't resemble that at all. Our parse trees look like this:

[image: My desired parse tree]

Or like this (using a slightly different notation that doesn't show the intermediate nodes):

[image: My desired parse tree 2]

I'm stuck for what to do. Are there any packages that will produce this kind of output that I haven't come across?

Comment: Duplicate of [What is the best package out there to typeset proof trees?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468)