# Scheme Proof Tree

Tags: trees

I'm currently working on making proof trees for regular expressions in scheme. The suggested way of writing these in the course I'm taking is the following, which I've manually typed into TeX.

[image: Proof Tree]

This however, is a tedious process, especially for long expressions. So what I am looking for is a sneaky way to make the type of proof tree shown above, or maybe an alternative, that can accomplish the same.

**Edit**:

Here is my code, I don't mind typing in the tree, but this way is really, really slow. So if there is a package that can do some of the positioning work for me I'd be a happy camper.

```
\phantom{ATOM}\ \ \ \ \ 1 is a Scheme integer\qquad\qquad\qquad (\%regexp (atom 2))\\
ATOM ---------------------\qquad\qquad SEQ ------------------------------------------------------------\\
\phantom{ATOM} (\%regexp (atom 1)) \qquad\qquad\qquad\ \ (\%regexp (seq (atom 2) (seq (atom 3) (seq (atom 4) (empty)))\\
\phantom{A}SEQ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\
\phantom{ATOM} (\%regexp (seq (atom 1) (seq (atom 2) (seq (atom 3) (seq (atom 4) (empty))))))
```

**Edit 2:**
I've not kind of found a solution with the `bussproofs` package, but it's still not optimal, it gets a bit odd looking when the prooftrees get big.

[image: Prooftree]

My code for creating this is:

```
\begin{prooftree}
\def\ScoreOverhang{1pt} 
\def\extraVskip{6pt}
\def\defaultHypSeparation{\hskip .2in}
\def\ruleScoreFiller{\hbox to1.1mm{\hss\vrule width0.9mm height0.4pt depth0.0pt\hss}}
\AxiomC{1 is a Scheme integer}
\LeftLabel{ATOM}
\UnaryInfC{(\%regexp (atom 1))}
\AxiomC{2 is a Scheme integer}
\LeftLabel{ATOM}
\UnaryInfC{(\%regexp (atom 2))}
\AxiomC{3 is a Scheme integer}
\LeftLabel{ATOM}
\UnaryInfC{(\%regexp (atom 3))}
\AxiomC{4 is a Scheme integer}
\LeftLabel{ATOM}
\UnaryInfC{(\%regexp (atom 4))}
\AxiomC{}
\LeftLabel{EMPTY}
\UnaryInfC{(\%regexp (empty))}
\LeftLabel{SEQ}
\BinaryInfC{(\%regexp (seq (atom 4) (empty)))}
\LeftLabel{SEQ}
\BinaryInfC{(\%regexp (seq (atom 3) (seq (atom 4) (empty))))}
\LeftLabel{SEQ}
\BinaryInfC{(\%regexp (seq (atom 2) (seq (atom 3) (seq (atom 4) (empty)))))}
\LeftLabel{SEQ}
\BinaryInfC{(\%regexp (seq (atom 1) (seq (atom 2) (seq (atom 3) (seq (atom 4) (empty))))))}
\end{prooftree}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you've actually typed to produce that? I'm not sure what you are looking for exactly. There are packages for this kind of tree, of course, but you still have to enter the code for the tree - TeX can't do that for you. Have you checked out the LaTeX for Logicians site?

Comment: @cfr I've now provided the code I'm using to create the output.

Comment: Did you look at this:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468/what-is-the-best-package-out-there-to-typeset-proof-trees  ?

Comment: Please include the required preamble and `document` environment. At least 2 packages provide `prooftree`, for example. (I know you say you use `bussproofs`, but not everyone will know that's the package which provides `prooftree`, especially if they know `prooftrees` provides `prooftree`.

Comment: Have you looked at newer options such as `ebproof`? `bussproofs` is very popular, though. Also, could you be a bit more specific re. what you mean about them looking 'odd'. What would you like to be different?

Comment: Also, how would you feel about inputting proofs backwards i.e. conclusion first?