# Tree with lines in latex

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, algorithms, trees

[image]

How can i input this on latex? I tried but the space is too hard to input and also  the line is hard to input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{P}
\AxiomC{$\neg P,Q$}
\BinaryInfC{Q}
\AxiomC{E}
\AxiomC{F}
\BinaryInfC{G}
\UnaryInfC{H}
\BinaryInfC{R}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

This produce similar but quite different can someone change it?

Comment: I've already seen this kind of stuff and I believe there is a dedicated package but I cannot remember the name. Would you provide some background?

Comment: @campa The name the package is ebproof. Best regards.

Comment: thankyou so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best package out there to typeset proof trees?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468/what-is-the-best-package-out-there-to-typeset-proof-trees)